# Speed difference between two same asp.net applicatin that use one database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, iis, pagespeed

I have an asp.net web application that works with a SQL Server database in one server that we call server 'A'. Application speed is good in our MAN Network

I publish our web application to another server (server 'B') that uses the database on Server 'A'.

We have very slow speed when call application from server 'B'.

The Network has no problem and when I call server 'A' application from server 'B' we don't have any deceleration

Both web application absoultely are same and use one database

I am really confused; what is the reason?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you transfer a lot of data from the database to the application? This is a lot slower when they are on separate servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Turned Off Firewall On All Server But No Changes Seeing. But when I Go To Windows FireWall ,
In Advanced Tab, In NetWork Connection Setting Section (In Windows Server 2003) And Uncheck All Connection.

My Speed Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0):

There are various things which play crucial role here.

- When you run the asp.net application from the same server where you have hosted the database, chances are more that sql server connection is either through "Named pipes" or "Shared memory". These both are very fast methods for communicating with the server compared to tcp ip. When you host the asp.net application on another server, it is forced to use tcp-ip for communication.
- Network can be good but you should also check other factors such as frame size and MSS on the network. Having a bigger frame size helps sql server to effectively use the entire available speed. Devices such as switches and routers attached in the network also plays a vital role.
- Apart from all, I doubt that your application is using an inappropriate architecture or following wrong practices. e.g. if you want list products, you can make a query to fetch all the products from the db and filter out the result to a specific page which is a wrong practice. Ideally, the query should only fetch those records which you want to display.
  Using data adapters instead of readers also causes such issue as they try to read the entire content and create an in-memory table.

Comment: I Have Several Copy Of My Applicatin On Server B That Each Of Them Connected To One SqlSever Of Servers A But This Problem Seeing in Some Of Application And In The Other No Problem